# Redirect particular URL to an SSL version with SEO name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using this line of code to redirect a specific url to the ssl version and at the same time to show a short SEO friendly name:

```
RewriteRule ^signin$ https://server.com/login.php [L]
```

This works when the https is on, but when the user is on http the redirect occurs without the rewrite, and the address bar shows the full path

```
https://.../login.php
```

instead of

```
https://.../signin
```

Is there a way to make SEO name work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are not on HTTPS, then this causes an *external* redirect, because the protocols don’t match – and since your browser is explicitly told by the server to make a new request for `https://server.com/login.php`, this is what you see in the address bar.

You should do this in two steps: If `/signin` is requested and you’re not on HTTPS, then redirect to the HTTPS version of the same path. And then rewrite `/signin` *internally* (so without specifying protocol and hostname) to `login.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^signin$ https://server.com/signin [L]

RewriteRule ^signin$ /login.php
```